# How to go back to an old commit and merge with top of the branch?

Tags: git, version-control, github, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

I just realized and the top of our working branch is missing a vital commit I made. Most probably someone in my team wrote over this commit, his changes..

How can I go back to that commit and then re merge with the top of the branch?

I tried creating a branch with only my commit and then merging with the top of the main branch but git does an auto merge and just stacks all the changes that happened after my commit over this diverged branch that I created.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the commit already exists, you can use `git cherry-pick <sha1>` from your working branch to add it at the top.

If for some reason you need to put it in a certain order in the commit tree, you may prefer `git rebase -i <oldsha1>`, then stop at the commit you want to complete/add after/, and use `git cherry-pick` (or `commit --amend`) at this moment